# How to make a gallery with Image and text for android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gallery

I wanna make a Gallery, with a picture in the background and a textfield with invisible background... So I can see the text and the Image behind.

I already made the Gallery but i cant figure out how to put text in the foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a custom adapter to use for your gallery view, see [Hello Gallery tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)

In the method getView() you have **two different ways** to achieve the same result:

**A.** Make an ImageView and a TextView and set the image and text:

```
ImageView iv = new ImageView(context); //and so on, remember to set the LayoutParams etc to fit your design.
```

Make a RelativeLayout and add the ImageView and TextView to it

Return the RelativeLayout.

**B.** Declare a layout in xml, with a RelativeLayout containing a TextView and an ImageView

In getView, inflate this layout, and using

```
inflatedLayout.findViewById(R.id.myTextView); //and so on
```

set the text and image and return the layout.

Comment: and how can I use this layout for the gallery item?

Comment: see my updated answer, just ask if you need more clarification

Comment: ok thanks man!
But if i try it the way A, how can i return the layout? because the function wants a View? Sry for the stupid questions, but im relative new in Android :)

Comment: The layout inherits from View, see for example the [RelativeLayout documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html). I assume that you understand the concept of inheritance, or are you also new to object oriented programming?

Comment: no no ...
now i tried it the way B and I made it!
Tahnks again for helping! Very nice!